# Cannot login to 'postgres' database as 'postgres' user

Tags: database, postgresql, crash, psql, postgresql-8.4

I am unable to login to 'postgres' database as 'postgres' user.
OS : REHL Server release 6.3
Postgresql version: 8.4
There is a Database 'jiradb' which is used as a Backend for JIRA 6.0.8.

When I give the command

[root ~]#**psql postgres postgres**
Password for user postgres: *******
***psql: FATAL: could not open relation with OID 2696***

How do I fix this error and login to 'postgres' database. Please ask me if you need more details. I am new to postgres DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `postgres` database is damaged. oid 2696 is a system reserved oid, so it's a system table, and their oids are stable across databases and across versions. Looking it up on my 9.4, it's:

```
regress=> select relname from pg_class where oid = 2696;
             relname              
----------------------------------
 pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index
(1 row)

regress=> \d pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index
Index "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index"
   Column   |   Type   | Definition 
------------+----------+------------
 starelid   | oid      | starelid
 staattnum  | smallint | staattnum
 stainherit | boolean  | stainherit
unique, btree, for table "pg_catalog.pg_statistic"
```

so you have a *missing file* in the data directory for the index `pg_statistic_relid_att_inh_index` on the system table `pg_catalog.pg_statistic`.

This should not happen. You have at lest limited data corruption in your datadir.

Your first action should be to stop the database and make a full filesystem-level copy of the entire data directory, per [PostgreSQL wiki - corruption](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).

Then check for possible causes. Recent disk issues? Unexpected/sudden shutdowns followed by `fsck`, possibly on a system with a non-crashsafe file system, unsafe mount options (e.g. ext3/ext4 `data=writeback`), unsafe configurations like ext[34]-on-LVM-on-md with barriers on older kernels, etc. Also make sure you're on the latest 8.4 point release.

**Only once you have made a full file system level copy of the data directory to safe read-only storage**, start the database back up (but *not* the applications that use it) and see if you can connect to `jiradb` e.g. `psql jiradb`. If you can, **promptly perform a `pg_dump` of `jiradb` and any other databases with data of value**.

Do not keep on using the damaged data directory. Now is a good time to do a dump and reload - do a `pg_dumpall --globals-only`, a `pg_dump -Fc` of each database, then move the datadir aside, re-`initdb`, and start back  up with a clean install. You might even want to upgrade to a less ancient PostgreSQL at the same time.

---

Note that it is generally possible to fix issues like this in-place. In this case, if your damaged database wasn't the unimportant-and-usually-empty `postgres` database, you could start PostgreSQL up in single-user mode with system indexes disabled, then `REINDEX` the damaged index.